# AutoCompleteTextView doesn't suggest for just FIRST SEARCH

Tags: android, autocompletetextview, countdowntimer

**Aim :**

I want to get some strings from webservice and populate AutoCompleteTextView with them.This is simple but what I want actually is to begin search (invoke webservice) when typing finished.

I mean, for example, I type something and 3 seconds after typing finished, AutoCompleteTextView would get populated and suggestions show up.

**What I did so far :**

As you can see in the code below, I used a CountDownTimer to achieve this. I set it 3 seconds  and start it in OnTextChanged. When user type, I clear CountDownTimer and create a new instance of it and start it again.

So, whenever user type -on every key press- I reset counter.

After that, I call my method - which invoke webservice and populate AutoCompleteTextView -   in CountDownTimer's OnFinish().

**Problem :**

When I finish typing, everything works as expected as I can see in debug mode. But suggestions doesn't come up FOR ONLY FIRST SEARCH.

I mean, it works as well but AutoCompleteTextView doesn't get populated with data for only FIRST TIME.

**Note :**

I invoke webservice both synchronous and asynchronous way.

```
counter=new MyCount(3000, 1000);
autoComplete.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            
            if(isBackPressed){  //catch from KeyListener, if backspace is pressed don't invoke web service
                
                isBackPressed=false;
                return;
            }
                
            String newText = editable.toString();
            
            searchText=newText;
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {


        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            if(isBackPressed){
                
                isBackPressed=false;
                return;
            }
                
            counter.cancel();
            counter=new MyCount(3000, 1000); 
            counter.start();
        }

    });
```

Here is my CountDownTimer Class

```
    public class MyCount extends CountDownTimer{

    public MyCount(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {

    super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);

    }
    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        
        invoke_webservice(searchText);
    }
    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        
    }
    }
```

Here is my method to invoke webservice in synchronous way

```
public void invoke_webservice(String key){
    
    try{
                    . //code to invoke webservice and populate string [] results
                    .
                    .
    aAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.item,results);
    autoComplete.setAdapter(aAdapter);
    aAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    
}
```

Here is my method to invoke webservice in asynchronous way

```
class getJson extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... key) {
        
        String newText = key[0];

                    . //code to invoke webservice and populate string [] results
                    .
                    .

        
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                
                aAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.item,results);
                autoComplete.setAdapter(aAdapter);
                aAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        
        return null;
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: please don't add duplicate posts for same problem, merge your posts so people don't waste their time looking and answering both posts. This usually considered as spamming  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143308/android-autocompletetextview-filter-is-firing-late-for-the-first-search-only

Comment: @Mayank the link above is not working...please check

Comment: I think user have deleted his post that's why the link is not working anymore. He had same question in another post, so I just pointed out to him that it is not a good idea to do that and can be considered spamming.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do:
i have set the threshold value to 3

```
 atvSearchPatient.setThreshold(3);
```

apply the text watcher listener on autocomplete text view like below:

```
 //here set the text watcher
    atvSearchPatient.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            String str = atvSearchPatient.getText().toString().trim();
            if (str.length() >2) {

                    searchPatient(str );

            } 
        }
    });
```

on your first call hit API with null values and for second and consecutive calls with string from autocomplete textview field as above.and then in response apply the adapter like below:

```
this.nameList.clear();
    if (nameList.size() > 0) {
        this.nameList.addAll(dataFromResponseList);
        atvSearchPatient.setAdapter(null);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(
                this, android.support.v7.appcompat.R.layout.select_dialog_item_material, nameList);
        atvSearchPatient.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        atvSearchPatient.showDropDown();
```

It's weired problem for first time not working but that's the only way working in my case nothing else. hope it helps
Thanks